# Input text and button with icon

Tags: javascript, button, textbox

How can I implement a input text and very close to it a button. I want it to look like one element (when I put a textbox and next to it a button, there's a space between both - that's what I'm trying to avoid.

How can I do it?

Comment: There's this nice thing called CSS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can used Bootstraps `<div class="input-append">` to append a button onto a input.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms
check out "extending form controls"